# In an android application like talking tom how we can find which region is touched?

Tags: android, touch

I want to know in an android app like talking tom, how we can detect which region is touched? any help?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [The proper way to detect which region of an Android.ImageView is touched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279216/the-proper-way-to-detect-which-region-of-an-android-imageview-is-touched)

Answer (score 2):

This is very basic. Please look at this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html